# python "reference to" vs "copy of" dictionary item

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the following code running under 2.7.6, I'm using argparse to get the command line params into a kwargs dictionary. then I make a copy of one item and change it. I get a different result depending on whether the dictionary item starts out empty or not.

The routine is expecting a positional command line param such as `COM6,9600,8,none,1`, which goes into the COM key, but I want to provide default params for everything but the com port.

```
#split up COM params entered as comma delimited
cp  = kwargs['COM']
if len(cp)==1:
     cp = cp[0].split(',')

# provide defaults
if len(cp)<5:
     if len(cp)<4:
          if len(cp)<3:
               if len(cp)< 2:
                    if len(cp)==0:
                         cp.append('')       # no default port
                    cp.append(19200)         #baud
               cp.append(8)                  #databits
          cp.append('none')                  #parity
     cp.append( 1 )                          #stopbits                  

print cp
print kwargs['COM']
```

If I run `"python myprog.py"`, with no params then the print statement will be

```
['', 19200, 8, 'none', 1] 
['', 19200, 8, 'none', 1]
```

which is great. But I'm surprised that running `"python myprog.py COM6"` yields

```
['COM6', 19200, 8, 'none', 1] 
['COM6']
```

This means that in the first case it was copied by reference and the second was copied by value. The workaround is simple and trivial, just copy cp back into kwargs, but I'm confused by the result.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: How about you use a list of defaults and slice those based on how many values you already have, appending the sliced list? `cp += ['', 19200, 8, 'none', 1][len(cp):]`. That's 11 lines of nested `if`s replaced by one line..

Comment: I corrected your sample; you *must* be printing `cp` then `kwargs['COM']`. That detail would have lead to an answer faster. :-)

Comment: yes I was. sorry. The responses were so quick I've had trouble keeping up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code *rebinds* `cp` when there is just one element:

```
cp  = kwargs['COM']
if len(cp)==1:
     cp = cp[0].split(',')
```

`kwargs['COM']` and `cp` are now two distinct, separate lists.

If you wanted them to be the *same* list, use a slice assignment, perhaps:

```
cp  = kwargs['COM']
if len(cp)==1:
     cp[:] = cp[0].split(',')
```

Your deeply nested `if` structure didn't need to use nesting, and can be replaced by:

```
cp += ['', 19200, 8, 'none', 1][len(cp):]
```

e.g. slice a list of default values to size based on the number of elements already present in `cp`.

Comment: alright. I obviously need to do a little more reading about binding and slicing. This works and is elegant. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
cp  = kwargs['COM']
```

Once this line executes, `cp` and `kwargs['COM']` refer to the same object. If you append to it using either one, the change will be evident in the other.

```
     cp = cp[0].split(',')
```

Once this assignment occurs, `cp` rebinds, and now refers to a brand new list. It no longer has any relation whatsoever to `kwargs['COM']`. Appending to `cp` doesn't change `kwargs`.

In general, after an assignment, a name no longer has any memory regarding what it was previously bound to.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, you answer is equally correct. I just saw Martijn's first.